# How to press such a button through Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

```
<span class="">
        <a id="id3cc" href="javascript:;">TEXT</a>

        <div id="id3df">
            
        </div>
    </span>
```

The problem is that id is dynamic. I tried to bind to text, but this sometimes throws an error (works in debugger, but doesn't work on simple run). Here is my code and error.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"TEXT") ]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

This raises the error
no such element: Unable to locate element:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),"Показать контактную информацию") ]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.82)
```

How else can you get to this line?

Comment: can you share a link to that web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can bound it up with explicit wait, and I would suggest you to use `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`, since text is between an anchor tag.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "text between a tag"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should add wait / delay until the page is loaded and the element you trying to access is loaded.
Also possibly you have to scroll that element into view.
Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

element_xpath = "//a[contains(text(),'Показать контактную информацию')]"

driver.get("your_url")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath")))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('element_xpath')
actions.move_to_element(element).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try full with full xPath or you can use smartly write some xPath for parent element and then follow from there.
for example in URL [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
search bar can be located in a lot of way

```
full XPath = /html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input
short xpath = //form[@action="/search"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/input
```

or you can use find all `<a>` tags and then find your `a` tag in the list and click it.

Comment: Do not try it. This suggestion is not good.